# Save the data in the list to another table

Tags: c#

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddVotes(List<CampaignManager_tbl> list, int events_category_id, int candidates_info_id) {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var events = db.Events_Info_tbl.Where(x => x.is_active == true).FirstOrDefault();
            var username = User.Identity.Name;
            var getID = db.Account_Info_tbl.Where(x => x.username == username).FirstOrDefault();

            foreach (var i in list)
            {
                Votes_tbl vote = new Votes_tbl();

                vote.candidates_info_id = i.candidates_info_id;
                vote.C_voters_info_id = getID.account_info_id;
                vote.events_info_id = events.events_info_id;
                vote.events_category_id = i.events_category_id;
                vote.votes_history = true;
                db.Votes_tbl.Add(vote);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(list);
    }
```

This is my code where I am going to save the data in the list into the database but it is not working. `List<CampaignManager_tbl> List` contains the data to be saved in the Votes_tbl.

What's wrong with this code? How I am gonna save this data?

Comment: First, i'd suggest to move the "db.SaveChanges();" out of the foreach... no need to save each time you run, second, what error are you getting?

Comment: start using the debugger for starters and so not call the `db.SaveChanges()` until you are finished processing data within the loop

Comment: Ive got this error."DbUpdateException was unhandled by user code".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult AddVotes(List<CampaignManager_tbl> list)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var events = db.Events_Info_tbl.Where(x => x.is_active == true).FirstOrDefault();
            var username = User.Identity.Name;
            var getID = db.Account_Info_tbl.Where(x => x.username == username).FirstOrDefault();

            foreach (var i in list)
            {
                int val = 1;
                bool y = Convert.ToBoolean(val);
                if (i.isSelected == y) {
                    Votes_tbl vote = new Votes_tbl();

                    vote.candidates_info_id = i.candidates_info_id;
                    vote.C_voters_info_id = getID.account_info_id;
                    vote.events_info_id = events.events_info_id;
                    vote.events_category_id = i.events_category_id;
                    vote.votes_history = true;
                    db.Votes_tbl.Add(vote);
                }              
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
        return View(list);
    }
```

I've come up to this solution but anyway thanks for giving advices. It helps a lot. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Save your data outside the loop.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddVotes(List<CampaignManager_tbl> list, int category_id, int candidates_info_id) {

if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var events = db.Events_Info_tbl.Where(x => x.is_active == true).FirstOrDefault();
        var username = User.Identity.Name;
        var getID = db.Account_Info_tbl.Where(x => x.username == username).FirstOrDefault();

        foreach (var i in list)
        {
            Votes_tbl vote = new Votes_tbl();

            vote.candidates_info_id = i.candidates_info_id;
            vote.C_voters_info_id = getID.account_info_id;
            vote.events_info_id = events.events_info_id;
            vote.events_category_id = category_id;
            vote.votes_history = true;
            db.Voters_Info_tbl.Add(vote);


        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(list);
}
```